# How to declare an object in Angular JS that isn't a service but doesn't pollute the global scope?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I've since discovered I can return instances of an object by having a get() method in my factory, that returns new service instances.

But what if my object isn't a service (talking semantics here). E.G I have a page with many charts on it, the chart object (below) isn't (semantically) a service.

So do I have to declare it using something like factory/provider/etc pattern? It feels wrong, as it's not actually a service. But I need to reference it from my controller, so it needs to be injected, or accessible somehow. & I don't want it to pollute the global scope.

```
var Chart = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.initialize = function (name, clientMethod, usingDateRange, usesAnalytics, initCB, serviceCB, highchartsConfig) {

        this.name = name;
        this.clientMethod = clientMethod;
        this.usingDateRange = usingDateRange;
        this.usesAnalytics = usesAnalytics;
        this.initCB = initCB;
        this.serviceCB = serviceCB;
        this.highchartsConfig = highchartsConfig;

        this.$chart = $('#' + name);
        this.isIncluded = false;

        this.highchartsConfig.chart.renderTo = this.name;

        this.initCB && this.initCB(this);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Look at `module.value()`. From doc:

> Register a value service with the $injector, such as a string, a number, an array, an object or a function. This is short for registering a service where its provider's $get property is a factory function that takes no arguments and returns the value service.

## UPDATE

Not sure if you are still interested in it, but I finally found a correct answer to your question - make use of the `$controller` service. [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/aDpWdH9DvKsYEXdw9yzo?p=preview) I  created a simple demo:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $controller) {

  function Person($interpolate, name, surname){
    var greetStr = "Hello {{name + ' ' + surname}}!";
    var greetExp = $interpolate(greetStr);
    this.greet = greetExp({name:name, surname:surname});
  }

  $scope.person1 = $controller(Person, {name:"Jack", surname:"Daniels"});
  $scope.person2 = $controller(Person, {name:"Johny", surname:"Walker"});
});
```

*(I used `$interpolate` **just** to show that angular's DI will automatically resolve any dependencies it is aware of. The rest of dependencies [locals] may be passed as the second argument to the `$controller`.)*

Comment: @Baconbeastnz yes, indeed.

Comment: I need a non-singleton. But in any case, is it correct to say then, that any custom object, that one writes, (when using angular), should be declared in one of these value/factory services? No matter what the semantics are? (Just seems like semantically unintuitive?